# MySQL COUNT() with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, join, count

I am building a course system, with courses, instructors and a table to relate the two.

Symplified table `instructors`:

```
id | name | ...
```

Symplified table `courses`:

```
id | name | instructors_needed | ...
```

Symplified table `link`:

```
id | course_id | instructor_id
```

I created the following query to fetch the names of the instructors associated to a particular course:

```
SELECT i.name, c.name, c.instructors_needed FROM courses c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    link
ON c.id = link.course_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    instructors i
ON link.instructor_id = i.id
```

This works fine. I created the following query to find the number of instructors on each course:

```
SELECT COUNT(i.name) as number, c.id, c.name, c.instructors_needed FROM courses c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    link
ON c.id = link.course_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    instructors i
ON link.instructor_id = i.id
GROUP BY c.ID
```

I want to combine the two queries, to get all details about the instructors for a particular case, but also the total number of instructors on the course and the number of instructors needed. How do I do that? I understand that the GROUP BY is the problem here.
I searched but I could only find examples with 2 tables instead of 3, and I somehow can't figure it out for three tables.

Your help is really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: rule of the thumb: whenever you come into the need of using un-aggregated fields ( aka columns not used with summing up functions like, count/sum/average ) and aggregated ones, list all the un-aggregated fields in the GROUP-BY statement. So you most likely only need to write `GROUP BY c.ID, c.name, c.instructors_needed` ( this is of course alot "dumbed down" and GROUP BY has several good other uses espec together with HAVING)

Comment: Hello Najzero, thanks for responding!
I tried your suggestion but this gives me a maximum of 1 instructor name for each course.
But @Edper 's solution did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT i.name, c.name, c.instructors_needed, Ctr.CourseCount FROM courses c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 link
ON c.id = link.course_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  instructors i
ON link.instructor_id = i.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT link.course_id, COUNT(*) as CourseCount FROM link GROUP BY link.course_id) Ctr
ON link.course_id = Ctr.course_id
```